# Is it possible to change the website in every 5 seconds automatically?

Tags: windows-7, website

Here's what I want - I have 3 websites which almost constantly change - **A**, **B** and **C**. I want **A** to displayed at first. After **5** seconds, website **B** should appear and after 5 seconds , website **C** should appear , and so on. Is this even possible ? If yes , please suggest how.

Comment: Is this just for your viewing only or do you want this to happen to visitors to your sites?

Comment: It's only for my viewing

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: @James Watt Nothing... I was just curious...Thanks Everyone !

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is going to be to create your OWN website, one page for each site and setup a frame on each page.

Embed one website inside the frame only for one of the sites you want to refresh. Use javascript to refresh the page.

You could do this using local .html files on your desktop, you don't have to actually buy web hosting and do this work.

You could even get creative and put a second frame at the top/bottom that says "Start/Stop Refresh" in case you wanted to pause it.

For help creating such a page, consider www.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

Use js's window.open method, call each window from the window that called them to do a window.refresh via a setTimeout(func, int miliseconds), where func recursively calls setTimeout (so that it keeps repeating).

ie,
psudo javascript

```
window.open(window1, ...
window.open(window2, ...
window.open(window3, ...

setTimeout(dothatthingIsaid,5000)

func dothatthingIsaid(){
  window1.refresh()
  window2.refresh()
  window3.refresh()
  setTimeout(dothatthingIsaid,5000)
}
```

edit:
Sorry guys, thought I was on stack overflow for some reason. Do'h.

Answer (score 1):

Back in 2010, you could just create a HTML page with a full-size frame (`<iframe>` or otherwise) and cycle its address using JavaScript. This is what Ouroborus’ and James Watt’s answers suggest.

Unfortunately, things aren’t as easy nowadays. To prevent various types of attacks, new security measures are now in place. Sites can use the [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) header or the newer [`frame-ancestors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) directive inside a `Content-Security-Policy` header to control who can embed the page. From some anecdotal experience, this is already widely deployed. A frame isn’t going to cut it anymore. *All* modern browsers enforce these restrictions. Even Internet Explorer!

There are two options, but they’re more work:

1. Create a custom browser
2. Create a browser extension

Both options may seem impossible to achieve for the average person, but worry not.

Creating a custom browser is very easy nowadays. There’s Electron and WebView2. Both take the existing Chrome/Chromium browser engine and provide a programming interface to interact with it. Think frames on steroids! You would then use basically the code/logic from Ouroborus’ answer and cycle the URL the custom browser window displays. All this requires a basic idea of NodeJS (JavaScript) or C#/C++ desktop application programming.

A browser extension can do pretty much the same, but using an existing browser like Firefox or Chrome. It can take control of a tab and cycle the URL it displays, again using the same logic. Or it could cycle multiple tabs. There’s some minor difficulty concerning mandatory signing of browser extensions. This way requires JavaScript programming.

There’s even an [existing extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-rotator/) that could probably do (most of) what is desired. I haven’t tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a html file with this content and load it in your browser:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
html,body,iframe{height:100%;width:100%;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;}
html,body{overflow:hidden;}
</style>
<iframe></iframe>
<script>
var timer = 5;
var sites = [
    'http://www.bing.com/',
    'http://www.ask.com/',
    'https://duckduckgo.com/'
];
var frame = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0];
var index = 0;
var cycle = function() {
    frame.src = sites[index];
    if(++index>=sites.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(cycle,timer*1000);
}
cycle();
</script>
</html>
```

Configure the `sites` array with the urls you wish to cycle through. `timer` controls cycle time in seconds.

Keep in mind that some sites do not permit framing (e.g.: google) and there is a mechanism that most browsers support that follows this.